# Custom tabLayout is not working in Api level 24 and 25

Tags: java, android

Api level 24. The design is fully responsive but still not showing the custom tabLayout, How can i solve this problem for older version of android device. [Api level 24 picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSoke.png)

Api level 33, it is working fine on all other devices expect api level24 and 25.  [Api level 33 picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avZTN.png)

Please help me to show the tablayout in older version of android device.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.